# Trick to find nearest point in a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

The question starts off by defining $W$ as the span of the set

${(3, 2, 3)^t, (-2, -2, -2)^t, (1, 0, 1)^t}$,

and $b$ as

$(1, 2, -3)^t$

Part a) asks to find the nearest point $w$ in $W$ to $b$, which I found as

$(-1, 2, -1)$

Part b) asks to calculate $dist(b, W)$, which I calculated as $\sqrt{8}$

Finally part c) ask find the nearest point $w'$ in $W$ to

$b' = b   \ +\ (1, 1, 1)^t = (2, 3, -2)^t$

Obviously I could just recalculate $b'$ using the same steps in a), but I am thinking there is a shortcut to it. I can see that the magnitude of $b'$ will be $\sqrt{3}$ more than that of $b$, but I am stuck from here.

Comment: You might want to go back and check your work for part (a). If the $w$ you found is indeed the closest point to $b$, then $w-b$ should be orthogonal to each of the vectors that define $W$. It’s not orthogonal to _any_ of them.

Comment: Hint for part (c): What’s the relationship between $(1,1,1)^T$ and $W$?

Comment: @amd My bad, there was a typo. That is certainly a good way to check my answer however so thanks. I'll work with the hint for now

Comment: So far I can see that  $(1,1,1)^T$ is in the span of $W$

Comment: Span of W can be reduced to 2 vectors $(1,0,1)^{T}$ and $(0,1,0)^T$. W is a plane since it has 2 vector basis in dimension 3. Since a plane and a line (non-parallel with respect to the plane) will always intersect, in this case in point ${(0,0,0)}$.